# How do I disable background tracing in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I use sp_configure  on SQL 2005 (full edition)  to disable these 200MB mulithreaded traces that are going on in the background and filling up my hard drive?

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\audittrace_20061029095619_4.trc

---

Thanks for the answer.  Here was the fix:

```
c:\> osql -E
> sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
> go
> RECONFIGURE
> go
> sp_configure 'c2 audit mode', 0
> go
> RECONFIGURE
> go
Then restart SQL server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of [Enabling and Disabling C2 Auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196700%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

However before you do turn this off, hadn't you better check as to why they are on in the first place? Do you have a business requirement for C2 Audit Traces to be turned on?

If you do have a requirement to keep them, you could write a script to move them every so often to a suitable secure location. By default they are written to the default data directory selected on install. If this is a problem you may be able to change the location of the default data directory but will probably require bouncing the services for it to take affect.

To change the default database file location, open SQL Server Management Studio and right click the Server object, select Properties and then Database Settings.

Comment: this was on a DEV system.  didn't need it to be on and i dont know how it got "on".

Comment: i guess the problem may be that im using a full version of sql instead of the DEV version for development...

Comment: Dev edition is the same as the "full version" sql server enterprise.  Only the licensing is different